# search in angular 4

Tags: angular2, typescript

Доброго времени суток! Делаю поиск на angular что-то не выходит помогите разобраться.

app.component.html:

```
<div class="container master">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="../logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="row col-xs-10">
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           [(ngModel)]="queryString"
           placeholder="type phone number/name to find...">
  </div>
  <div class="row col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>owner</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let phone of phones | FilterPipe: queryString">
        <td>{{ phone.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ phone.number }}</td>
        <td>{{ phone.owner }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterPipe } from './pipes';

export class Phone {
    id: string;
    number: string;
    owner: string;
}

const phoneList: Phone[] = [
    { id: 1, number: '200', owner: 'Соколов Николай' },
    { id: 2, number: '225', owner: 'Петров Петр' },
    { id: 3, number: '200', owner: 'Иванов Иван' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'pb',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Phone Book';
  phones = phoneList;
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FilterPipe } from './pipes'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

pipes.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'FilterPipe',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, input: string) {
    if (input) {
      input = input.toLowerCase();
      return value.filter(function (el: any) {
        return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
      })
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пару замечаний по коду:

1. Придерживайся строгой типизации. Например `transform(value: Phone[], input: string)` вместо `transform(value: any, input: string)`, твоя бы ошибка определилась на этапе компиляции.
2. Имена pipe делай в camelCase
3. Для моделей лучше использовать `interface` чем `class`. Проще выполнять преобразование raw json.

`export interface Phone {
    id?: string;
    number?: string;
    owner?: string;
}`

Comment: Спасибо, я только начал его изучать еще не все тонкости изучил)
Подскажите, а как не выводить таблицу если не нашлось ничего из поиска, пробовал через *ngIf не вышло

Comment: Напиши свой вариант кода

Comment: пробовал через else в pipe, но там не выйдет.
вот так - <table class="table" *ngIf="queryString"> - выходит не совсем то, с пустой строкой ничего не показывает

Comment: Во первых нужно заинжектить пайп в `AppComponent`, например как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-use-pipes-in-services). во вторых обернуть вызов `transform` в метод компонента `check(query: string):boolean { return this.filterPipe.transform(this.phoneList, query).length > 0}`. И соответственно `<table class="table" *ngIf="check(queryString)">`

Comment: заинжектить пайп в AppComponent - это не совсем понял

Comment: Получить в компоненте ссылку на пайп для вызова метода transform: `constructor(private filterPipe: FilterPipe) {}`

Comment: описывать ее полностью надо ?

Comment: Property 'phoneList' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

Comment: спс, разобрался, надо было:
  check(query: string): boolean {
    return this.filterPipe.transform(this.phones, query).length > 0
  }
и в providers добавить пайп

Comment: Такой способ помог?

Comment: Да, все ок, спасибо)

Comment: но теперь появилась проблема при компиляции:

**ERROR in ng:///C:/project/phonebook/src/app/app.component.html (10,5): Property
'queryString' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.**

Comment: исправил объявив это в AppComponent, только не понятно зачем он там:
queryString: string;

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, input: string) {
    if (input) {
      input = input.toLowerCase();
      return value.filter(function (el: any) {
        if (el.number.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
          return el.number.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        }
        if (el.dep.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
          return el.dep.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        }
        if (el.owner.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
          return el.owner.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        }
      })
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```